# If population of a city be modeled by $P(t) = 40e^{0.07t}$ thousand persons, where t is the number of years after $2000$. Then calculate the following

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> The population of a city can be modeled by $P(t) = 40e^{0.07t}$ thousand persons, where t is the number of years after $2000$.

> Approximately how rapidly was the city's population be changing between $2029$ and $2036$?

> The city's population was changing by ________
> thousand persons/year.

*My solution :**

Given,  $P(t) = 40e^{0.07t}$, where $t$ is the number of years after $2000$

Therefore the population in $2029$ and $2036$ respectively are $P(29)$ and $P(36)$.

Now, the required rate of growth is $$\frac{P(36)-P(29)}{36-29} \\
= 27.5114 \ \ \ \text{thousands/year}.$$

It's my first time attending a problem like this. Can you please confirm if my logic is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: You calculation is correct. But I would say that the  city's population be changing between 2029 and 2036 $\textrm{on average}$ $27511.4$ persons per year.  In my view the term "approximately" is not really necessary here, since we do not use an approximation method.

Comment: Yes I thought of it. But that's just there in the question so I typed it here. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.